# simple css apply background-color only on anchor

Tags: html, css

I want to apply a background color to only my anchor tags and NOT the font-icon. I nested the < span > because I need the icon to also be clickable.

If i take that span fa-fa-angle-down class and put it outside the anchor, everything looks good ( **this is what I want** ), but it's not clickable.

```
<span class='http_method'>

          <a href='test' class="toggleOperation"> <span class="fa fa-angle-down"></span> method</a>
          </span>
```

```
span {
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 0;
}

.http_method a{ background: linear-gradient(#4c99d7,#1a66a3);
    border: 1px solid #1a66a3;
    height: 25px;
    line-height: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.http_method span{
font-size: 30px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #686b6d;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/c2Ln1cab/1/

Comment: check you fiddle link mate?

Comment: my bad i updated it

Comment: I re-read your question a few times and cannot understand what your problem is. Can you rephrase it?

Comment: The simplest thing would be to set the background color of the arrow to the color of whatever is behind it.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/c2Ln1cab/2/  This is what I want. But my fa-font is not clickable. I want the entire thing to be clickable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just add a span for what you want the gradient on and then you can have both inside the anchor?

```css
span {
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 0;
}

.http_method a {
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.http_method a span.gradient{
  background: linear-gradient(#4c99d7, #1a66a3);
  border: 1px solid #1a66a3;
}
.http_method span {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #686b6d;
}
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<span class='http_method'>
 
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<span class='http_method'>
 
<a href='test' class="toggleOperation"> 
<span class="fa fa-angle-down"></span><span class="gradient">method</span>
</a>
</span>

</span>
```

Comment: why is there a small - beside method??

Comment: There is a space. If you get rid of it it goes away

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving the anchor tag, styling, think about creating a new class with that style, and apply that class wherever needed.

This way you are not depended on tags and are not constraining the construction (HTML) with style (CSS).

```css
span {
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 0;
}

.http_method .link{ background: linear-gradient(#4c99d7,#1a66a3);
    border: 1px solid #1a66a3;
    height: 25px;
    line-height: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.http_method span{
font-size: 30px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #686b6d;
}
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 

<span class='http_method'>
<a href='test' class="toggleOperation"><span class="link">method</span>
 <span class="fa fa-angle-down"></span>
 </a>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/c2Ln1cab/4/

Answer (score 0):

Just put the spans inside the anchor, an them work from there:

Example:

html:

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<a href='test' class="toggleOperation">

 <span class="fa fa-angle-down"></span><span class="span-colored">method</span>

</a>
```

css:

```
span {
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 0;
}

.http_method a:not(span){ background: linear-gradient(#4c99d7,#1a66a3);
    border: 1px solid #1a66a3;
    height: 25px;
    line-height: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;

}

.http_method span{
font-size: 30px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #686b6d;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/c2Ln1cab/5/